# Android Studio - uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 7 cannot be smaller than version 9 declared in library

Tags: android-studio, google-play-services, android-manifest, android-min-sdk

Until now I had `android:minSdkVersion="7"` in my app. Later I had to add google play services that require a `minSdkVersion="9"`. And I got this error:

```
uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 7 cannot be smaller than version 9 declared in library
[com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0] C:\AppsFolder\MyApp\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services\8.4.0\AndroidManifest.xml
```

I didn't really mind setting a higher minSdk so I changed it to  `android:minSdkVersion="9"`

But I still get the same error...I cleaned and rebuilt the project many times but this keeps happening. Somehow Android Studio still sees the  `android:minSdkVersion="7"` somewhere. Any ideas how to fix this?

I'm using Android Studio 1.5.1

Comment: please show all your App gradle file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are changing `minSdkVersion` directly in `AndroidManifest.xml` file. Android Studio uses gradle files for those settings and not manifest file.

You should remove those entries from manifest and edit your application `build.gradle` file (located in your project root/app/ folder)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.yourdomain.yourpackage"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
...
```